Why can't an interface directly extend an indexed access type?
I have a type, and an interface that extends it:
type IntrinisicDivProps = JSX.IntrinsicElements['div'];

interface SomeComponentProps extends IntrinisicDivProps {
  // added properties
}

That works great. However, it seems to me I shouldn't need to make the IntrinisicDivProps type. After all, I'm essentially saying "A = B, extend from B", so shouldn't I be able to say "extend from A, directly"?
I would have expected this to work:
interface SomeComponentProps extends JSX.IntrinsicElements['div'] {
  // added properties
}

... but it doesn't.  I get:
An interface can only extend an identifier/qualified-name with optional type arguments.ts(2499)

How does my IntrinisicDivProps have "optional type arguments", but JSX.IntrinsicElements['div'] doesn't, even though one literally = the other:
type IntrinisicDivProps = JSX.IntrinsicElements['div'];

Aren't they the same thing?

'"An interface can't extend an expression" would probably be clearer'. 'How does my IntrinisicDivProps have "optional type arguments"' - it doesn't, but an identifier or qualified name could.

Think of it as a syntax restriction and not a semantic restriction.  There's an open issue at... oh look, @jonrsharpe just linked it. Okay, he can write an answer...

So if I'm understanding correctly, it's a "TS is dumb" problem?  TS sees an expression and throws the error because it knows expressions can contain un-extensible stuff (like an identifier or qualified name) ... even though my particular expression doesn't.  Putting it in a type variable somehow tells TS "this expression has no identifiers or qualified names"?

Of course by "dumb", I just meant that the tool is unable to understand the contents of the expression ... I'm not trying to insult TypeScript :)

Certainly TS is unable to "understand" it; it's a syntactic restriction. You can extend named types, including generic named types, not arbitrary type expressions. Some named types are still not extendible (e.g., type A = {a: string} | {b: number}; interface C extends A {} will fail). It's an unimplemented feature. The issue linked above is the canonical answer to this question. Does this suffice if someone writes it up? Or are we still missing something about this question?

I think I get it: before I put it into a type, the expression is just an expression, but after I put it into a type it's a named type.  TS is just written, syntactically, to let you extend named types and not extensions (presumably because there'd be something confusing about allowing expressions?).  To put it another way, in TS after you do type x = y, x !== y (because at that point x is a type, and y is an expression).  If I have that right, more or less, I just need an answer to accept :)

It's a missing feature of TypeScript, requested at microsoft/TypeScript#31843.  Currently there is a syntactic restriction on what kinds of types can be extended by an interface. That means even if two types are semantically identical, they might be treated differently if they are written with different syntax. Syntactically, you can only extend "an identifier/qualified-name with optional type arguments", meaning, mostly, that it has to be a named type (where "optional type arguments" means it can be a named generic type as well.) This syntactic restriction isn't necessary for anything, which is why the above feature request is open instead of declined. But that's the way it currently is.
But this means you can always work around this restriction by using a simple generic type alias
type Named<T> = T;

And it works because now the syntactically prohibited type becomes a type argument, which is allowed:
interface SomeComponentProps extends Named<JSX.IntrinsicElements['div']> {
}

Note that this doesn't let you sidestep the semantic restriction to only extend object types or intersections of object types with statically known members (as implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#13604):
interface Oops extends Named<{ a: 0 } | { b: 1 }> { } // error, union
interface Whoops<T> extends Named<T> { }// error, unknown properties
interface Nope<T> extends Named<
  T extends string ? { a: 0 } : { b: 1 }
> { } // error, generic conditional

Playground link to code
